# How do I construct an oauth api call?

Tags: python, perl, bash, oauth, tumblr

I'm trying to get tumblr "liked" posts for a user at the http://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/likes url. I have registered my app with tumblr and authorized the app to access the user's tumblr data, so I have `oauth_consumer_key`, 
`oauth_consumer_secret`, `oauth_token`, and `oauth_token secret`. However, I'm not sure what to do with these details when I make the api call. I'm trying to create a command line script that will just output json for further processing, so a solution in bash (cURL), Perl, or python would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you don't mind using Python I can recommend [rauth](https://github.com/litl/rauth). There isn't a Tumblr example, but there are [real world, working examples](https://github.com/litl/rauth/tree/master/examples) for both OAuth 1.0/a and OAuth 2.0. The API is intended to be simple and straight forward. I'm not sure what other requirements you might have, but maybe worth giving it a shot?

Here's a working example to go by if you're interested:

```
from rauth import OAuth1Service

import re
import webbrowser

# Get a real consumer key & secret from http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/apps
tumblr = OAuth1Service(
    consumer_key='gKRR414Bc2teq0ukznfGVUmb41EN3o0Nu6jctJ3dYx16jiiCsb',
    consumer_secret='DcKJMlhbCHM8iBDmHudA9uzyJWIFaSTbDFd7rOoDXjSIKgMYcE',
    name='tumblr',
    request_token_url='http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token',
    access_token_url='http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token',
    authorize_url='http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize',
    base_url='https://api.tumblr.com/v2/')

request_token, request_token_secret = tumblr.get_request_token()

authorize_url = tumblr.get_authorize_url(request_token)

print 'Visit this URL in your browser: ' + authorize_url
webbrowser.open(authorize_url)
authed_url = raw_input('Copy URL from your browser\'s address bar: ')
verifier = re.search('\oauth_verifier=([^#]*)', authed_url).group(1)

session = tumblr.get_auth_session(request_token,
                                  request_token_secret,
                                  method='POST',
                                  data={'oauth_verifier': verifier})

user = session.get('user/info').json()['response']['user']

print 'Currently logged in as: {name}'.format(name=user['name'])
```

Full disclosure, I maintain rauth.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of found an answer. I ended up using OAuth::Consumer in perl to connect to the tumblr API. It's the simplest solution I've found so far and it just works.